# CUDA: Launching many parallel calls to cuBLAS on different subsections of a matrix, without serializing

Tags: matrix, memory-management, cuda, cublas

In my application, I have a double complex N*3 matrix (where N is several thousand) and a 3*1 vector, and I am forming an N*1 using zgemv.

The N*3 is a subsection of a larger M*3 matrix (where M is slightly larger then N, but the same order of magnitude).

Each thread must perform a zgemv call to a different subsection of the larger matrix. That is, the N*3 is different for every thread. But all of the N*3 are formed from some portion of the larger M*3.

There isn't enough memory for each thread to store an independent N*3. Furthermore, the M*3 is too large to fit in shared memory. Thus each thread must pull its data from a single copy of the M*3. How can I do this without  millions of threads serializing memory reads to the same memory locations in the M*3? Is there a more efficient way to approach this?

Comment: Are you really using cuBLAS? If yes why do you need to consider something about shared memory?

Comment: When you say "thread" do you mean CPU thread or GPU thread?  Stated another way, are you already using CUDA Dynamic Parallelism to launch the zgemv calls from device code (i.e. GPU threads), or do you have many CPU threads that are launching zgemv calls from host code? Is each N*3 subset of the M*3 matrix a contiguous subset (i.e. is it N adjacent rows)?  You've said N is several thousand, and I believe I can infer that M is no larger than 10,000.  How many threads are there, i.e. how many actual calls to CUBLAS zgemv are being made?

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for you reply. I am (trying to use) dynamic parallelism for zgemv. There are approximately 1e6 threads that each use a subset of the larger matrix. Each subset is contiguous in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, based on what I can gather so far, there are 2 types of optimizations I would want to consider:

1. convert operations that use the *same* N subset to a matrix-matrix multiply (zgemm), instead of multiple zgemv operations.
2. cache-block for the GPU L2 cache.

I'll discuss these in reverse order using these numbers for discussion:

- M: ~10,000
- N: ~3,000
- cublas zgemv calls: ~1e6
- "typical" Kepler L2: 1.5MB

An Nx3 matrix requires approximately 10,000 elements, each of which is 16 bytes, so let's call it 160K bytes.   So we could store ~5-10 of these subsets in a memory size comparable to L2 cache size (without taking into account overlap of subsets - which would increase the residency of subsets in L2).

There are (M-N) possible unique contiguous N-row subsets in the M matrix.  There are 1e6 zgemv calls, so on average each subset gets re-used 1e6/M-N times, approximately 100-150 times each.  We could store about 10 of these subsets in the proposed L2, so we could "chunk" our 1e6 calls into "chunks" of ~1,000 calls that all operate out of the same data set.

Therefore the process I would follow would be:

- transfer the M*3 matrix to the device
- predetermine the N*3 subset needed by each thread.
- sort or otherwise group like subsets together
- divide the sorted sets into cache-sized blocks
- for each block, launch a CDP kernel that will spawn the necessary zgemv calls
- repeat the above step until all blocks are processed.

One might also wonder if such a strategy could be extended (with considerably more complexity) to L1/Texture.  Unfortunately, I think CDP would confound your efforts to achieve this.  It's pretty rare that people want to invest the effort to cache-block for L1 anyway.

To extend the above strategy to the gemm case, once you sort your zgemv operations by the particular N subset they require, you will have grouped like operations together.  If the above arithmetic is correct, you will have on average around 100-150 gemv operations needed for each particular N-subset.  You should group the corresponding vectors for those gemv operations into a matrix, and convert the 100-150 gemv operations into a single gemm operation.

This reduces your ~1e6 zgemv operations to ~1e4 zgemm operations.  You can then still cache-block however many of these zgemm operations will be "adjacent" in M and fit in a single cache-block, into a single CDP kernel call, to benefit from L2 cache reuse.

Given the operational intensity of GEMM vs. GEMV, it might make sense to dispense with the complexity of CDP altogether, and simply run a host loop that dispatches the ZGEMM call for a particular N subset.  That host loop would iterate for M-N loops.

Comment: Thank you very much for your well thought out and insightful response. I am going to give a flavor of this a try and see what happens.